# SQL Query - find the number of unique data entry

Tags: sql

I have the following table named FruitCountry and I would like to check number of unique entries per fruit, I think I can achieve that by first `grouping` by fruit then countryID, then select distinct data and use `COUNT()` function to find the size, yet is there a less tedious way to achieve that? Thanks!

```
Fruit CountryID
-----------------
Apple         1
Apple         2
Apple         1         
Grapes        3
Grapes        3
```

```
Fruit    # of unique entries
-----------------
Apple         2
Grapes        1
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just count the unique countryid.

```
select Fruit,  count(distinct CountryId) 
from FruitCountry 
group by Fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

Use count(distinct columnname) to achieve distinct count of a column within the group:

```
select Fruit,  count(distinct CountryId) [# of unique entries]
from FruitCountry 
group by Fruit
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have large amount of data it is a good idea to use a temporary table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#fruits') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #fruits
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #fruits(Fruit VARCHAR(10), Id INT )
--INSERT INTO #fruits
INSERT INTO #fruits ( Fruit, Id ) VALUES ('Apple', 1 )
INSERT INTO #fruits ( Fruit, Id ) VALUES ( 'Apple', 2 )
INSERT INTO #fruits ( Fruit, Id ) VALUES ('Apple', 1 )
INSERT INTO #fruits ( Fruit, Id ) VALUES ('Grapes', 3 )
INSERT INTO #fruits ( Fruit, Id ) VALUES ('Grapes', 3 )

--SELECT * FROM #fruits
--Temp Table to hold Distinct Values
CREATE TABLE #temp (Fruit VARCHAR(10) , Id INT )
INSERT INTO #temp (Fruit, id ) SELECT DISTINCT Fruit, id  FROM #fruits 

--Final Query to get NoOfUniqueEntries
SELECT Fruit, count (*) AS NoOfUniqueEntries  FROM #temp 
GROUP BY Fruit

DROP TABLE #temp, #fruits
```